# How to get Date Pickers for multiple EditorFor in a single page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

In My view I have 4 EditorFor fields which I want to make as DatePickers

```
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date1)            
</div>  

<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date2)            
</div>  
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date3)            
</div>   
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date4)            
</div>
```

I have implemeted EditorFor Template like this

```
@model System.DateTime?

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.css" />
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",(Model == DateTime.MinValue)? null : Model), new { @class="text"})
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {        
        $("#@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName").datepicker({            
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
            gotoCurrent: true,
            pickTime: false
        });      
    });

</script>
```

But when DatePickers only works for the first EditorFor Control which is

```
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date1)            
</div>
```

and it does not work for the rest of the three
Could you please any one tell me how to get date pickers for rest of the three EditorFor controls, Thanks

Comment: Never put scripts in partials or editor templates - move it to the main view (or the layout). And you template is not necessary at all.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather add some css class to those editors:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date1, new { @class = "date-picker"});
```

and then just use single script with selector:

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker({...});
```

That should work for all your fields.

Answer (score 0):

@Stephen Muecke right.

But if you still want to use your template. Move this part to your Layout:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.css" />
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

So your editor template will be:

```
@model System.DateTime?

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",(Model == DateTime.MinValue)? null : Model), new { @class="text"})
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {        
        $("#@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName").datepicker({            
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
            gotoCurrent: true,
            pickTime: false
        });      
    });

</script>
```

Comment: No, the script also needs to be moved to the main view. And the first thing OP needs to do is delete the editor template (its nonsense)

Comment: @StephenMuecke but why he need to move script? I mean i know, that it's bad practice (hard to debug for example), but sometimes it's reasonable to place them here and it will work.

Comment: Its just nonsense to repeat the same script over and over again. And the other code in the template is even worse :).